# Get all Images except "base image" and "small image"

Tags: product-images

I would like to output all Images except 'base image' and 'small image' for an image Slider. Right now this code below outputs all Images:

```
    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $_product->getImage()): ?>

    <div class="row slider clearfix">
        <div class="column full slide ratio4_3">

        <ul class="bxslider product">
            <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
                <li>
                  <div class="sliderContent">
                  </div>
                  <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" class="sliderImage" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

What is the best way to display all Images not tagged with anything?

Comment: You can go to the backend and check the "Exclude" checkbox for the images you don't want shown in the media gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the comments....

You can go to the backend and check the "Exclude" checkbox for the images you don't want shown in the media gallery.

All the images that have this "exclude" checkbox checked are ignored by the `getGalleryImages` method.

Comment: Thank Marius...+1from me.

Comment: What if need to do this programmatically?  i have a situation where images are used on two places how i can get them  with custom code? @Marius♦